# Objective-C iPhone - Ordering data within multiple sections of a UITableView dataSource

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

For the purpose of asking this question about ordering. The following `MyObject` class returns an instance with random generated category names.

I use the following `dataSource` methods:

`numberOfSections` accessed with `[dataSource count]`.

`titleForSection` accessed with `[[dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"categoryName"]`.

`numberOfRowsInSection` accessed with `[[[dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"myObjects"] count]`.

And finally, the `MyObject` for each row is accessed with `[[[dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"myObjects"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` on the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

I use the following code to create a `dataSource` that displays 9 section categories, however I'm a little stuck on the ordering of these categories and the data within. Assume there's an `NSDate` property as part of the `MyObject` class.

*Question:* How would I go about using this to display the records in descending order?

```
- (void)createDatasource
{
    NSInteger numberOfObjects = 10;
    NSMutableArray *objects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numberOfObjects];
    NSMutableArray *categories = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numberOfObjects];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
    {
        MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
        [objects addObject:obj];
        [categories addObject:obj.category];
        [obj release];
    }
    NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:categories];
    NSMutableArray *dataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[set count]];
    for (NSString *categoryString in set)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *mainItem = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:nil, @"categoryName", nil, @"myObjects", nil];
        NSMutableArray *mainItemMyObjects = [NSMutableArray array];
        [mainItem setValue:categoryString forKey:@"categoryName"];
        for (MyObject *obj in objects)
        {
            if ([obj.category isEqualToString:categoryString])
            {
                [mainItemMyObjects addObject:obj];
            }
        }
        [mainItem setValue:mainItemMyObjects forKey:@"myObjects"];
        [dataSource addObject:mainItem];
        [mainItem release];
    }
    NSLog (@"objects = %@\ncategories = %@\nset = %@\ndatasource = %@", objects, categories, set, dataSource);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest would be to sort your arrays, using [NSMutableArray's sorting mutators](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-SW6) or [NSArray's sorting methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW12). Otherwise you'd have to construct some sort of mapping from input indices to dataSource indices for use by the various data source methods.

---

**Edit** Requested sample code for sorting, something like this should work. I assume you are wanting to sort everything by a property named `date` on the MyObject.

```
// First, sort the myObject mutable array in each category
for (NSDictionary *d in dataSource) {
    [[d valueForKey:@"myObjects"] sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id o1, id o2){
        // Compare dates. NSDate's 'compare:' would do ascending order, so if we just
        // reverse the order of comparison they'll come out descending.
        return [[o2 date] compare:[o1 date]];
    }];
}

// Second, sort the categories by the earliest dated object they contain
[dataSource sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id o1, id o2){
    // Extract the first object from each category's array, which must be the
    // earliest it contains due to the previous sort.
    MyObject *myObject1 = [[o1 valueForKey:@"myObjects"] objectAtIndex:0];
    MyObject *myObject2 = [[o2 valueForKey:@"myObjects"] objectAtIndex:0];

    // Compare dates, as above.
    return [[myObject2 date] compare:[myObject1 date]];
}];
```

Comment: I'm fine with sorting my arrays. It's the issue with sorting the sections along with those arrays.

Comment: If you have each of the row arrays sorted, you can sort the sections based on the first object in each section's row array. Or you could sort the sections by something completely different if that suits your dataset better.

Comment: @Anomie Would you mind providing a bit of code to do exactly that?

Comment: @Anomie Thanks for this. The second portion of code seems to be working properly however with the first I'm getting an error on this line: [[d valueForKey:@"myObjects"] sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id o1, id o2); the error I'm getting is: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI sortUsingComparator:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc367bc0'.

Comment: That error message indicates that you have a plain NSArray rather than an NSMutableArray as the code you posted above shows. Use an NSMutableArray, or use NSArray's `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` method and then save the sorted array back into the dictionary.

Comment: @Anomie I had some previous sorting code and forgot to remove it. Thanks for all your help, this worked perfectly in the end.